# How to show an action sheet inside the popover?

Tags: ipad, controller, action, popover

I have a split View controller, in which the left side holds a table view controller. How do I show an action sheet inside the popover when I click on the detail disclosure button of the table cell?

Answer (score 15):

Try this :

```
UIActionSheet *popupSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"No Way !" 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

popupSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
UIButton * disclosureButton = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

[popupSheet showFromRect:disclosureButton.bounds inView:cell.accessoryView animated:YES];
[popupSheet release];
```

The [UIActionSheet docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state that the `showFromRect:inView:animated:` method:

> displays the action sheet in a popover whose arrow points to the specified rectangle of the view (in our case the detail disclosure button). The popover does not overlap the specified rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for more **advanced use:**

1. finds custom accesoryView (cell.accesoryView)
2. if empty, find generated accesoryView (UIButton) if cell has
3. if the UIButton doesn't exists, find cell contet view (UITableViewCellContentView)
4. if the cell contet view doesn't exists, use cell view

Can be use for **UIActionSheet** or **UIPopoverController**.

**Here is my code:**

```
UIView *accessoryView       = cell.accessoryView; // finds custom accesoryView (cell.accesoryView)
if (accessoryView == nil) {
    UIView *cellContentView = nil;

    for (UIView *accView in [cell subviews]) {
        if ([accView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            accessoryView   = accView; // find generated accesoryView (UIButton) 
            break;
        } else if ([accView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellContentView")]) {
            // find generated UITableViewCellContentView                
            cellContentView = accView; 
        }
    }
    // if the UIButton doesn't exists, find cell contet view (UITableViewCellContentView)           
    if (accessoryView == nil) { 
        accessoryView   = cellContentView; 
    }
    // if the cell contet view doesn't exists, use cell view
    if (accessoryView == nil) {
        accessoryView   = cell; 
    }
}

[actionSheet showFromRect:**accessoryView.bounds** inView:**accessoryView** animated:YES];
```

Tested in iOS 4.3 to 5.1

**Best to use as custom method:**

```
-(UIView*)getViewForSheetAndPopUp:(UITableViewCell*)cell;
```

And method code:

```
-(UIView*)getViewForSheetAndPopUp:(UITableViewCell*)cell {
UIView *accessoryView = cell.accessoryView;

if (accessoryView == nil) {
    UIView *cellContentView = nil;

    for (UIView *accView in [cell subviews]) {
        if ([accView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            accessoryView = accView;
            break;
        } else if ([accView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITableViewCellContentView")]) {              
            cellContentView = accView;
        }
    }       

    if (accessoryView == nil) {
        accessoryView   = cellContentView;
    }
    if (accessoryView == nil) {
        accessoryView   = cell;
    }
}

return accessoryView;
}
```